# What is the maximal $m$, such that $\mathbb{Z}_2^m \leq GL(n, 2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, linear-groups

Is there any closed formula for the function $m(n)$, that is defined as the maximal $m$, such that there is $GL(n, 2)$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2^m$?

The only things I know currently, is that $m(1) = 0$ (as $GL(1, 2)$ is trivial) and $m(2) = 1$ (as $GL(2, 2)$ is isomorphic to $S_3$). With $GL(3, 2)$ the things become very complicated (as it is a simple group of order 168), so $m(3)$ or any other $m(n)$ with $3 \leq n$ is unknown to me currently.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that in the title where it says $\mathbb Z_2^n$ you mean $\mathbb Z_2^m$? Also, in the title you say "maximal" but in the text you say "minimal" -- I guess you mean "maximal"?

Comment: I believe the answer is $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Claim: $m(n)\geq\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$**.

**Proof:** For all $1\leq a\leq n-1$, there exists a subgroup of $GL(n,2)$ isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{a\times(n-a)}$, given by

$$
\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}I_{a\times a} & A \\ 0 & I_{(n-a)\times(n-a)}\end{matrix}\right)\middle|A\in(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{a\times(n-a)}\right\}.
$$

When $a=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$, we have $a(n-a)=\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$.

I believe $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$ is the best possible. This might be proved by looking at the subgroup of all upper-triangular matrices in $GL(n,2)$, which is one of the $2$-Sylow subgroups of $GL(n,2)$.